# How to show only message when the page has loaded instead of flickering text - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've seen different questions related to display message on page loading but in none of them there was example in which function was getting called inside `useEffect` itself.

**Problem:**

Anyways, moving to the problem, I'm getting flickering text which changes from `"Unauthorized Access"` to `"Authorized"` atleast couple of times (my assumption is due to state change) and so on which doesn't look good from User experience perspective.

**What I expect?**

Is there a way to only show `"Unauthorized Access"/"Authorized"` message without flickering text?
[image]

```
const User = () => {
  const [type, setType] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const isCancelled = useRef(false);

  const getUserType = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/API_ROUTE");
    const { type, error } = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok || error) {
      if (!isCancelled.current) setError(error);
      // console.log("failure", error);
    } else {
      // console.log("success", type);
      if (!isCancelled.current) setType(type);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted1");
    getUserType();
    setIsLoading(false);

    return () => {
      isCancelled.current = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>
      {isloading
        ? "Loading..."
        : type !== 2
        ? "Unauthorized Access"
        : "Authorized"}
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for async function `getUserType` to finish before setting `isLoading` to false:

```js
getUserType(); // this is asynchronous, you should await it.
setIsLoading(false); // You set `isLoading` to `false` before the actual fetching has finished
```

A simple solution would be to call `setIsLoading(false)` within `getUserType`, after fetching the data.

Comment: I kinda understand your point, now after moving `isLoading` at the end of the function, it's still flickering. I'm not sure if I can create some working demo as I'm using API. Do you have any other suggestions on replicating this behavior?

Comment: You can create CodeSandbox and mock the fetch function.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably update your `isLoading` flag after proper type has been set.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("mounted1");
   getUserType();

   return () => {
     isCancelled.current = true;
   };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   setIsLoading(false);
}, [type, error]);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still flickers

Comment: That should work, but you need to add a condition because it will be run when either type or error are still `undefined`.